# Looking for something like `let` in `match` expression

Tags: f#

Sometimes I use something like this:

```
match foo a with
| 1 -> printfn "%s" (foo a)
| 0 -> printfn "ok"
```

In this case I call `foo` function twice and if it is expensive call I use this code:

```
let tmp = foo a
match tmp with 
| 1 -> printfn "%s" tmp
| 0 -> printfn "ok"
```

But in this case I have created variable with outer scope (regarding `match` expression).

I am looking for something like this:

```
match (foo a) as tmp with
| 1 -> printfn "%s" tmp
| 0 -> printfn "ok
```

What do you use in this cases ? Is there any elegant solution ?

**Update** - real example:

```
let collection = getValuesFromDatabase a
match Array.length collection with 
| 0 -> printfn "nothing"
| _ -> bar collection.[0]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm oversimplifying but you know that `foo a` produced a constant 1, why not just print that directly?

Comment: @JeffMercado, I have added more realistic example.

Comment: if you concerned with the scope why not to wrap that code in the function and let the caller to return result of the new function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option 1: use a let- or do-block

```
let result =
    let tmp = foo a
    match tmp with
    | 1 -> printfn "%d" tmp
    | 0 -> printfn "ok"
```

Nesting the whole thing under a `let`-block keeps from polluting the namespace with `tmp`. The syntax is a bit heavy, but in return it allows for arbitrary complexity of the local computation.

Alternatively, if your result is a `unit`, you can replace `let` with `do`:

```
do
    let tmp = foo a
    match tmp with
    | 1 -> printfn "%d" tmp
    | 0 -> printfn "ok"
```

### Option 2: use pattern aliasing

When pattern-matching, you can match a value with more than one pattern at once, separating the patterns with `&`, e.g.:

```
match [1;2;3] with
| (x::_)&(_::y::_) -> printfn "First element is %d, second element is %d" x y
```

Here, I am matching the same list with two patterns: `x::_` and `_::y::_`. The example is a bit silly (I could have just matched with `x::y::_`), but it conveys the idea.

In your example, you can use this mechanism to capture the whole value by matching it with a trivial pattern:

```
 match foo a with
 | 1&x -> printfn "%d" x
 | 0 -> printfn "ok"
```

### Update: the "real" example

This is in response to your edit, where you provided a "real" example, which deals with a collection.

This "real" example is actually different from the "toy" examples that you provided before, in that you want to capture `collection`, but you're matching on `Array.length collection` - not the same thing. In general, there is no shortcut for this, except putting it in a nested `do` or `let` block as described above. But in your specific case I could rewrite the match like this:

```
match getValuesFromDatabase a with 
| [||] -> printfn "nothing"
| xs -> bar xs.[0]
```

Here, instead of calling `Array.length`, I match the value with an empty array. This way, since I'm matching the collection itself, I can capture it in the second match case and use it to get the first element.

If you wanted to perform a more complex check than just the empty array check, you could also use a pattern guard:

```
match getValuesFromDatabase a with 
| xs when Array.length xs = 0 -> printfn "nothing"
| xs -> bar xs.[0]
```

Comment: The [spec §7.2](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/) calls it a _variable pattern_: `If long-ident is a single identifier that does not begin with an uppercase character, it is interpreted as a variable pattern. During checking, the variable is assigned the same value and type as the pattern input.`

Comment: Is the any way to apply `pattern aliasing` to **real example**  in the **update**-part of my question ?

Answer (score 3):

In your real example, you can just use `if`. You are not really pattern matching on any complex data type which is where `match` shines. If you're testing whether a collection is empty, you can just write something like:

```
let collection = getValuesFromDatabase a
if Array.length collection = 0 then printfn "nothing"
else bar collection.[0]
```